# Глобальные функции в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу написать функцию ,видимую везде, принимающую имя таблицы и дальше вытягивать из нее данные.

```
def get_model(m)
  case m
  when 'book'
    Book
  when 'author'
    Author
  ...
    ...
  end
end

current_table = get_model(m)
```

Пытался сделать как указано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289065/rails-universal-global-function) может быть что то делаю не так

Comment: А какую задачу вы решаете? Есть подозрение, что решаете не в ту сторону

Comment: Добрый день, нашел более красивый способ в одну строку. Object.const_get("role".capitalize) # Получение объекта (таблицы в БД) из строки

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно можно создать файлик /config/initializers/global_foo.rb следующего содержания

```
module MyAppName
  class Application
    class << self
      def get_model(m)
        case m
        when 'book'
          Book
        when 'author'
          Author
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

И в где-угодно в коде использовать

```
current_table = MyAppName::Application.get_model(m)
```

На всякий случай уточню, что подобные трансляции строк в классы можно делать проще:

```
"book".classify.constantize
# Book (call 'Book.connection' to establish a connection)
```

Comment: Спасибо, красивый метод, но как оказывается можно делать и через контроллеры.